# Simple toolkits for emotion (sentiment) analysis (not using machine learning)

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am looking for a tool that can analyze the emotion of short texts. I searched for a week and I couldn't find a good one that is publicly available. The ideal tool is one that takes a short text as input and guesses the emotion. It is preferably a standalone application or library.

I don't need tools that is trained by texts. And although similar questions are asked before no satisfactory answers are got.

I searched the Internet and read some papers but I can't find a good tool I want. Currently I found SentiStrength, but the accuracy is not good. I am using emotional dictionaries right now. I felt that some syntax parsing may be necessary but it's too complex for me to build one. Furthermore, it's researched by some people and I don't want to reinvent the wheels. Does anyone know such publicly/research available software? I need a tool that doesn't need training before using.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the [Fietstas](http://fietstas.science.uva.nl/) library/web service that my colleagues are building does this out of the box. I'm not sure if the code is publicly available yet; they're currently planning a 2.0 release.

Comment: Thanks. You can change it into answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe [EmoLib](http://dtminredis.housing.salle.url.edu:8080/EmoLib/) could be of help.

Comment: This isn't a library or web service, so doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you will not find a more accurate program than SentiStrength (or SoCal) for this task - other than machine learning methods in a specific narrow domain. If you have a lot (>1000) of hand-coded data for a specific domain then you might like to try a generic machine learning approach based on your data. If not, then I would stop looking for anything better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Identifying entities and extracting precise information from short texts, let alone sentiment, is a very challenging problem specially with short text because of lack of context. Hovewer, there are few unsupervised approaches to extracting sentiments from texts mainly proposed by Turney (2000). Look at that and may be you can adopt the method of extracting sentiments based on adjectives in the short text for your use-case. It is hovewer important to note that this might require you to efficiently POSTag your short text accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer. I am currently not working on this any more.